# Why does rejecting a documentation change lead to an error?

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-proposals

I tried to reject this [change on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/8860).

I chose "Other" with the text: `No text changes were made in this change.`

I always get this error message:

[image]

Comment: I see the exception that's throwing. Will fix.